# jQuery slide animation of 2 divs and stop slide when it hits an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have some questions about jQuery animations.

But first, This is what I have currently. http://jsfiddle.net/ssmm0714/00vkoopn/

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="app-lst">

        <li class="item-6">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-7">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="icon closed"><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/5mixcx1j3/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow-img"></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-8">
            <a href="#">

            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like the green div to slide with bouncing effect (like easeOutBounce) and push  the yellow div out until only the green div's arrow is shown, and the contents of the green div will appear.
(It's like a sliding card effect?)

Currently, I made it so that the arrow spins on click.

Could someone help me with coming up with the desired effect? I tried doing a slide on both, but I do not know how to stop it when the blue div hits the arrow.

Also, as a side question, is it a good practice to put all widths of each divs in percentage form? I did this because this is going to be a mobile web app, and wanted to make it responsive.

Anyways, for reference,

This is the mock up of what I want it to look like after.
http://jsfiddle.net/ssmm0714/9q04nz0d/

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="app-lst">

        <li class="item-6">
            <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-7">
            <a href="#">
                <div class="icon closed"><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/5mixcx1j3/arrow.png" alt="arrow" class="arrow-img"></div>

                    <span> I AM THE HIDDEN TEXT! (loaded different HTML file) </span> 
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item-8">
            <a href="#">

            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? You didn't accept/vote it yes... please do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add the bouncing effect you will need the jquery-ui lib.
Next thing - you want both the yellow div and the green div to have the same effect (for the hide and show) and the effect should work the same time.

```
$('li.item-6').animate({'width' :'0'}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
$('li.item-7').animate({'width' :'100%'}, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w84btwsf/1/
Note that I added some workaround to handle small screens and problems with percentages (you can see it in the top of the js part).

Regarding your question about percentages - yes, this is indeed a good practice. You can also use one the the many css-frameworks that helps with developing responsive layouts ([bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is one of them).